# Почему при переборе set выходит undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
function unique(arr) {
  let set = new Set(arr);
  console.log(set);
  console.log(set.size);
}

let values = ["Hare", "Krishna", "Hare", "Krishna",
  "Krishna", "Krishna", "Hare", "Hare", ":-O"
];
console.log(unique(values));
```

Comment: Потому что ваш unique ничего не возвращает

Comment: `console.log(...set);`

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть, примерно так

```js
function unique(arr) {
  let set = new Set(arr);
  return [...set];
}

let values = ["Hare", "Krishna", "Hare", "Krishna",
  "Krishna", "Krishna", "Hare", "Hare", ":-O"
];
console.log(unique(values));
```